# Structural design for testing a gate system

Tags: vhdl, mux

I'm working on experiment 3 in the book Fundamentals of Digital and Computer Design with VHDL. This is what it wants. [image: experiment3]

I have Modules 1,2,and 3 all working individually. It's when I try to get them together in the top module that I start having issues. When I tried to simulate the program it failed, and I'm not sure how to fix.

```
--Module 1
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Displetter is
    Port ( mux_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Cath : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           An : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end Displetter;

architecture Behavioral of Displetter is

begin
  process(mux_in)
  begin
      if(mux_in = '0') then
                Cath <= "11000111"; --L pgfedcba 0s are what's lit up
      elsif (mux_in = '1') then
                Cath <= "10001001"; -- H pgfedcba
      end if;
  end process;

  An <= "0111";
end Behavioral;

--Module 2
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity MUX8 is
    Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);
           MUXOUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
end MUX8;

architecture Behavioral of MUX8 is

begin
    MUXOUT <= D(0) when (S="000") else
            D(1) when (S="001") else
            D(2) when (S="010") else
            D(3) when (S="011") else
            D(4) when (S="100") else
            D(5) when (S="101") else
            D(6) when (S="110") else
            D(7);

end Behavioral;

--Module 3
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Displetter is
    Port ( mux_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Cath : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           An : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end Displetter;

architecture Behavioral of Displetter is

begin
  process(mux_in)
  begin
      if(mux_in = '0') then
                Cath <= "11000111"; --L pgfedcba 0s are what's lit up
      elsif (mux_in = '1') then
                Cath <= "10001001"; -- H pgfedcba
      end if;
  end process;

  An <= "0111";
end Behavioral;


--Top Module

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TopMod is
    Port ( s6 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           s7 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Cath : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           An : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           s0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           s1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           s2 : in  STD_LOGIC);
end TopMod;

architecture Behavioral of TopMod is

COMPONENT Gates
  PORT(
      s6 : in  STD_LOGIC;
         s7 : in  STD_LOGIC;
         a0 : out  STD_LOGIC;
         a1 : out  STD_LOGIC;
         a2 : out  STD_LOGIC;
         a3 : out  STD_LOGIC;
         a4 : out  STD_LOGIC;
         a5 : out  STD_LOGIC;
         a6 : out  STD_LOGIC;
         a7 : out  STD_LOGIC
      );
  END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT MUX8
  PORT(
    D : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
      S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0);      
    MUXOUT : OUT std_logic
    );
  END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT Displetter
  PORT(
    mux_in : in  STD_LOGIC;
      Cath : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
      An : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0))
  );
  END COMPONENT;

  signal mout;
begin
  GATE : PORT MAP(
    s6 => s6;
    s7 => s7;
  );
  MUX : PORT MAP(
    D<7> => a7,
    D<6> => a6,
    D<5> => a5,
    D<4> => a4,
    D<3> => a3,
    D<2> => a2,
    D<1> => a1,
    D<0> => a0,

    s<0> => s0,
    s<1> => s1,
    s<2> => s2
    MUXOUT => mout
  );

  Disp : PORT MAP(
    Cath => Cath,
    An => An,
    mux_in => mout
  );

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Start by reading the error message when it failed, and searching for info on what it means.

Comment: Your question appears [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*  You're missing the entity/architecture for gates in addition to a plethora of syntax errors. Fixing syntax errors is like peeling an onion, more will be reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some of the most obvious issues I noted. Please consider trying some of the following and reporting the actual errors you're seeing.

**You need signals to hook the components up**

In your top architecture, all your a0...a7 ports need signals to wire the components together.

**Component instantiations**

After you have declared components, instantiate them with:

```
labelname: componentName
```

Also, you need round brackets in your port maps.

Consider putting your components in separate files as well if you don't have that already, it may make the error messages easier to read.